# JQuery is not loading xml from success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

I Have a jQuery that posts to a php file and returns xml. I can't seem to load and alert the specific field part_note. In the Jquery I Have a alert of the 'data' and it shows the returned xml. Any Help would be appreciated.

The XML It loads is:

```
<qdbapi>
    <record>
        <related_bid>48</related_bid>
        <part_note>This is a note 1</part_note>
        <record_id_>24</record_id_>
        <update_id>1417012758913</update_id>
    </record>
</qdbapi>
```

My jQuery:

```
$.post('/business/data/update_detail.php' , field_userid + "=" + value, function(data){
                if(data == 'error')
                {
                 var field = document.getElementById(field_userid);
                     document.getElementById(field_userid).className = "error";
                }
                else {

                  alert(data);
                  $(xml).find("record").each(function()
                  {
                    alert($(this).find("part_note").text());
                  });

                }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/business/data/update_detail.php",
  data: your_data_to_post,
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function(response_data) {
     //do what you want to do after POST 
  }
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error_string) {
   //do what you want to do if POST failed
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the explicit form of the $.ajax method, where the first argument is not a string, but an object, containing the dataType:'xml' explicitly. [Here's the API page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/test.php",
  dataType: 'xml' // magic is here!
}).done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a variable called `xml`; therefore your code should be as follows. And since your response is a string, you want to use `$.parseXML()` to parse the XML string.

```
  alert(data);
  var xml = $.parseXML( data );
  $(xml).find("record").each(function()
  {
      alert($(this).find("part_note").text());
  });
```

Here is a demo that shows how to parse it; actually you are just missing just one line: `var xml = $.parseXML( data );`. Everything else is fine.

```js
var data = 
'<qdbapi>\
    <record>\
        <related_bid>48</related_bid>\
        <part_note>This is a note 1</part_note>\
        <record_id_>24</record_id_>\
        <update_id>1417012758913</update_id>\
    </record>\
</qdbapi>';
alert( data );
var xml = $.parseXML(data);
$(xml).find("record").each(function() {
    alert($(this).find("part_note").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```